# Rails Gem with model-relationships for Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I'm just developing a Rails application which will have many Engines.
However, I'm not able to edit relationships inside the Engines.

To solve this issue, I want to create a relationships-Gem which will be included in the Application and defines the relationships (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835899/603126).

Let's assume, I have a User (namespaced and isolated) Engine and a Comment (namespaced and isolated) Engine.
What I want is to override / extend the relationships inside the relationships-Gem which will share the relationships.

So I added a file /app/models/comment.rb with these lines (to the relationships-Gem):

```
class Comment < CommentEngine::Comment
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < UserEngine::User
  has_many :comments
end
```

If I run my rails application, the relationships won't be established.

What am I missing?
How can this be achieved?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you post your controller's code where the associations are built (new and create actions)?

Comment: Inside the comments_controller:
def index
  @comments = current_user.comments
end

undefined method `comments' for #<UsersEngine::User:0x007fc4a64ffb10>

It seems like the model is never loaded. Even if I put a typo in the file, nothing happens.

Thank you very much!

Comment: On the stage of creation of a new comment, in CommentsController , how are your `new` and `create` actions look like ?

Comment: They are not implemented yet. I only have an index-action which looks like described above.

Comment: I suppose you are dealing with existing database records? You can take a look at this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) , look for point 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
so I've found a solution for that.

You can just monkey-patch your Engine with Decorators (you need to put it into config/initializers/initializer_name.rb)

see: [Extending a ruby gem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012383/extending-a-ruby-gem-in-rails)

Don't know if this is a good thing, but it works like a charm...

The downside is that you have to restart the server every single time you make a change to the monkey-patching...

EDIT: It seems that this monkey-patch will be garbage collected after a few requests.

EDIT 2:
This post helped me out
[How to monkey-patch code that gets auto-loaded in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460800/how-to-monkey-patch-code-that-gets-auto-loaded-in-rails)
you need to add thin sin your Intializer to force rails to reload your patch for every request

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
```

Answer (score 0):

The [activesupport-decorators](https://github.com/pierre-pretorius/activesupport-decorators) gem can load your decorators for you when the original class is loaded.